# Nest.JS MongoDB TypeormModule throws error "requires authentication"

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I have a nestjs app which uses typeorm and I am trying to connect to a mongodb (heroku addon). Somehow I can not solve it no matter what I do, I always get an authentication error

"command find requires authentication"

```js
   TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      username:"mydbusername",
      password:"mdbuserpassowrd",
      database:"mydbname",
      port:54681,
      url: process.env.ORMONGO_RS_URL,
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      ssl: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      authSource:"admin"
 
    }),
```

My connection string looks as follows (changed some values for security)

```
mongodb://iad2-c12-9.mongo.objectrocket.com:54681,iad2-c16-1.mongo.objectrocket.com:54681,iad2-c16-0.mongo.objectrocket.com:54681/?replicaSet=a72c9007b7bf4f2ead57d6532313123123&ssl=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't user `username` and `password` for type `mongodb` in typeorm, pass these values in URL. I had many times problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by myself, had to use another authSource (my actual dbname) rather than just admin.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `url` and set the `host` instead:

```
export const datasource = new DataSource({
    type: 'mongodb',
    host: ENV.DB_HOST,
    port: ENV.DB_PORT,
    ssl: ENV.DB_SECURE,
    authMechanism: 'DEFAULT',
    authSource: 'admin',
    username: ENV.DB_USERNAME,
    password: ENV.DB_PASSWORD,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    database: ENV.DB_NAME,
    // ...
});
```